# TypeScript () => void lambda function, understanding

Tags: typescript, lambda

I'm sitting and reading on some typescript code for Promises/A+ to get a better understanding on the inner workings.

I have hit a line i can't really understand.

```
static nextTickFn: (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function, caller: Promise) => void = (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function) => setTimeout(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn, 0);
```

So how does it work with the `(v: F, c: P) => void` work?
and how about when you add the equal `(v: F, c: P) => void = (v: F) => {}` after like that?

Basically I think the `=> void` is the thing that confuses me, but is someone could explain the entire method, and how to think about it, it would be nice.

Comment: it's just how you type a function that takes some parameters and returns nothing :-/

Comment: sorry, i might be dumb, what would the purpose of that be?

Comment: ups, okay now i got it, so the first part between the : and = is just the type definition... doh...!

Comment: yeah, it's an inline interface in typescript. :) you could make an interface out of it to be more explicit `interface OnNextTick { (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function, caller: Promise): void}` and use that instead `static nextTickFn: OnNextTick = (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function) => setTimeout(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line you want to understand:

```
static nextTickFn: (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function, caller: Promise) => void = (setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function) => setTimeout(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn, 0);
```

It has three portions:

1. `static nextTickFn`

   The name of the member
2. `(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function, caller: Promise) => void`

   The type annotation for the member
3. `(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn: Function) => setTimeout(setTimeoutOrSimilarFn, 0);`

   The value assigned to the member

You have `name:annotation = value`.

**See Also**: [Basic annotations](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system)

Comment: Thanks... Basically I was staring myself blind at it, as it's written as a var, but it was being used as a function. But thanks for clarifying. Literally felt stupid when I realized :-)